# How to wrap with a function a component which exports a factory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

In my reactjs app I am successfully using a component which returns a factory (I think this is the correct name).
In brief:

```
import { Auth } from "authenticator";


export default function SignIn() {
  ...
  const signIn = (e) => {
    Auth.signIn({username, password}).then((user) => {
       ...
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, factory functions return promises.
Now, I'd like to wrap the Auth factory with a function, let's say a throttle.
So, to avoid to wrap every Auth function call (Auth.signIn, Auth.signUp, Auth.forgotPassword, etc...) I'd like to wrap the Auth component inside another component of mine.
Somethinkg like this:

```
import { Auth } from "authenticator";
import { throttle } from "throttle";   

export default function ThrottledAuth() {
  return throttle(Auth);
}
```

The issue with this solution of course is that then I can't do - as I hoped - something like:

```
import ThrottledAuth from "./ThrottledAuth";

ThrottledAuth.signIn({username, password)}).then((user) => {
    ...
});
```

since I get: "Uncaught TypeError: promise.then is not a function", because Auth.signIn returns a promise.

Can you suggest the correct way to wrap a factory returning functions (which return promises)?

Comment: instead of using `throttledAuth`, try to using seperate `throttled method`
don't use `throttle(Auth)` try `throttle(Auth.signIn)` . but here again it need minor tweaks in throttle implementation

Comment: I di already tried `throttle(Auth.signIn)`, but got: `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function`. And I cannot tweak throttle, it's an external module.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came to this solution myself, which I don't like completely since it's quite dull...

```
export async function throttledSignIn(props, {success, error, final}) {
  throttle(
    Auth.signIn({...props})
      .then((result) => success(result))
      .catch((data) => error(data))
      .finally((data) => final(data))
   );
}
```

using it this way:

```
import { throttledSignIn, throttledSignUp, ... } from "./ThrottledAuth";

throttledSignIn({
  username,
  password,
}, {
  success: (user) => {
    ...
  },
  error: (err) => {
    ...
  },
  final: (data) => {
    ...
  }
});
```

I will not accept this answer, if there is a sleeker solution, I will be glad to read and adopt it...